# Where can I find a list of all audio file types supported by taglib-sharp?

Tags: .net, audio, tags, taglib-sharp

I don't know why this is so hard for me to find, but I simply can't find any documentation on this.  I just want to be sure I include support for all audio file types that taglib-sharp can work with and exclude all others.

All I've been able to find is a link to the source code and I really don't want to dig through it for such a simple question.  Thanks.

By the way, where is the "official" website?

EDIT:  After a little more research, it looks like the best answer I can find is in the file class documentation here:

http://taglib-sharp.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.0.3.7plus-pdfsg/classTagLib_1_1File.html

I was really looking for a list of supported audio file extensions, but this pretty much gives me what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the exact list of mime-types and extensions by searching the code for the following string: SupportedMimeType

You'll see the following for Mpeg.AudioFile.  The first parameter is the mime-type, and the second, if set, is the extension.

```
[SupportedMimeType("taglib/mp3", "mp3")]
[SupportedMimeType("audio/x-mp3")]
[SupportedMimeType("application/x-id3")]
[SupportedMimeType("audio/mpeg")]
[SupportedMimeType("audio/x-mpeg")]
[SupportedMimeType("audio/x-mpeg-3")]
[SupportedMimeType("audio/mpeg3")]
[SupportedMimeType("audio/mp3")]
[SupportedMimeType("taglib/m2a", "m2a")]
[SupportedMimeType("taglib/mp2", "mp2")]
[SupportedMimeType("taglib/mp1", "mp1")]
[SupportedMimeType("audio/x-mp2")]
[SupportedMimeType("audio/x-mp1")]
public class AudioFile : TagLib.NonContainer.File
```